# Как корректно настроить гостевую систему и виртуальную машину в virtualbox? (Не масштабируется экран, не работает клики мышью)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualbox

Помогите корректно настроить виртуальную машину. Установил ubuntu и дополнения гостевой ОС. Хочу развернуть систему на полный экран, включаю соответствующий режим и получаю вот такую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще в этом состоянии не работают клики мышью. Теперь если попробуем поменть разрешение через xrandr получим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перезайди на xorg сессию. заверши сеанс - нажми там на шестеренку - выбирай ubuntu на xorg.

Comment: Спасибо, добавлю только, что если вы логинетесь автоматически, gnome-session-quit --no-prompt поможет выйти из системы с нерабочей мышью.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу eri

При перезапуске системы Ubuntu опять стала использовать не ту сессию, поэтому пришлось редактировать конфигурационный файл.

Я его открыл в nano командой: `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` и добавил к демонам следующие две строки:

```
WaylandEnable=false
DefaultSession=gnome-xorg.desktop
```